# Change the colors of vectors?

Tags: plotting, visualization, vector

I'm using `ListVectorPlot` to draw vector fields. Is it possible to change the colors and also the types of the vectors?

Comment: You can find many things in the Documentation of  Listvectorplot like VectorColorFunction and VectorStyle

Answer (score 2):

You can use `VectorMarkers` to do this starting in V11.3:

```
data = Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];
Row@Table[
    ListVectorPlot[data, 
        ImageSize -> 200, VectorPoints -> 8, PlotLabel -> s, 
        VectorStyle -> Red, VectorMarkers -> s
    ], 
    {s, {"Arrow", "Segment", "Drop", "Pointer", "Toothpick"}}
]
```

[image]

`VectorMarkers` has nice autocompletions:

[image]

There is also `StreamMarkers` for controlling the appearance of elements in stream plots.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`VectorStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorStyle.html) to specify both the glyph and color:

```
data = Table[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3, 0.2}, {y, -3, 3, 0.2}];
Row @ Table[ListVectorPlot[data, ImageSize -> 200, VectorPoints -> 8, 
   PlotLabel -> s,  VectorStyle -> {s, Red}], 
 {s, {"Arrow", "Segment", "Drop",   "Pointer",  "Toothpick"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: .. afaik, this particular form of `VectorStyle` option setting does not appear in documentation.

Comment: I've reported the missing documentation to tech support at WRI.